# Swift: Calling an Enum value converter function as a first class function

Tags: swift, enums, coding-style, first-class-functions

```
enum SolarSystemPlanet: String, CaseIterable {
    case mercury, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune

    func toRawValue(_ value: SolarSystemPlanet) -> PlanetName {
        value.rawValue
    }
}
```

With the enum above, one way to get an array of planet names is to call

```
SolarSystemPlanet.allCases.map { $0.rawValue }
```

But Swift supports first-class functions, treating functions as "first class citizens", which allows us to call functions just like any other object or value.

So it would be nice to get an array of names by this

```
SolarSystemPlanet.allCases.map(.toRawValue)
```

However, it seems like the compiler needs more context. It couldn't infer a type in `map` at compile-time, so I did

```
SolarSystemPlanet.allCases.map(SolarSystemPlanet.toRawValue)
```

The compiler stops complaining, but I'm not getting an array of String. The line above returns a value of type `[(SolarSystemPlanet) -> String]`

If I printed the above out, instead of getting

```
["mercury", "venus", "earth", "mars", "jupiter", "saturn", "uranus", "neptune"]
```

I got

```
[(Function), (Function), (Function), (Function), (Function), (Function), (Function), (Function)]
```

If I forced the return type to be `[String]` like this

```
var planets: [String] = SolarSystemPlanet.allCases.map(SolarSystemPlanet.toRawValue)
```

Xcode would complain that `[(SolarSystemPlanet) -> String]` can't be converted to `[String]`

Is it possible after all to achieve what I'm trying to do? Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

And if it's not possible, I would also really appreciate some explanations on why.

Thanks for spending time reading my question!

---

Edit Thanks for [@sweeper](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5133585/sweeper)'s answer.

For those who are interested, I went slightly further to make sure every String enum has `toRawValue`

```
extension RawRepresentable where RawValue == String {
    static func toRawValue(_ value: Self) -> PlanetName {
        value.rawValue
    }
}
```

Note: This is Swift 5.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `toRawValue` doesn't need to be an instance method. It can be static:

```
static func toRawValue(_ value: SolarSystemPlanet) -> PlanetName {
    value.rawValue
}
```

Now you can use `SolarSystemPlanet.toRawValue` as the argument to `map`.

Alternatively, in this case, you can also use the *keypath* of `\.rawValue` as the argument to `map`:

```
SolarSystemPlanet.allCases.map(\.rawValue)
```

This is a new feature of Swift 5.2.

EDIT: Explanation of why instance methods don't work

In Swift, when accessed from a static context, an instance method on a type `T` that has the signature `(U) -> R` becomes a static method with the signature `(T) -> ((U) -> R)`. Instance methods need an instance of the enclosing type to call, right? So when you pass it a `T`, it gives you the original instance function `(U) -> R` back.

Therefore, the type of the non-static `SolarSystemPlanet.toRawValue` is

```
(SolarSystemPlanet) -> ((SolarSystemPlanet) -> String)
```

This explains why after `map` is applied, the array becomes a `[(SolarSystemPlanet) -> String]`.

Comment: Thanks so much! This is my first question and I didn't expect anyone to answer me this quick!

Comment: From my experience on Stack Overflow, if your question isn't too hard, it will be answered within an hour or 2.  @Tanin

Comment: any thoughts on why the instance method approach doesn't work? @Sweeper

Comment: Very clearly explained. Thanks again for your time @Sweeper.